# How to get the range axis tick interval in JasperReports?

Tags: java, charts, jasper-reports, jfreechart

I am using JasperReports to generate the PDF. I have a Line chart and it is generating some random tick intervals for different values in the chart.

I want to know the interval of the ticks.

I am using a customizer class and still I am not sure how can I get the values of the tick intervals.

I tried below mentioned functions but these are not helping

```
CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
NumberAxis axis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
_log.info("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ " + plot.getRangeAxisCount());
_log.info("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ " +   axis.getRange());
_log.info("@@@@@@@LENGTH@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ " + axis.getRange().getLength());
_log.info("@@@@@@@@@CENTRAL@@@@@@@@@@@@@ " + axis.getRange().getCentralValue());
_log.info("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ " + plot.getRangeAxisCount());
_log.info("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ " + plot.getRangeAxisCount());
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried axis.getTickUnit() in your customizerclass?
You can set the number of ticks with

```
axis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(20));
```

If you want no decimal ticks, go with

```
axis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
```

Comment: unfortunately  axis.getTickUnit()  always returns the same values 1 for different  ranges :( , Is there any other way